# Custom Aggregate function for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a table which contains three columns:

- ID
- Reference
- Description

I would like, for reporting purpose, to group the row with the same Reference and produce a `Description` which is a function of the two descriptions.

Is writing a `MERGED_DESCRIPTION(desc1,desc2)` possible in SQL Server 2008??

Comment: [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SQL CLR (the .NET integration into SQL Server) : yes

You can create your own [CLR User-Defined Aggregates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131057.aspx).

Comment: You can't create custom aggregates in T-SQL?